# Regex Help - Formatting \d{4}-0[1-9]|1[0-2].*

Tags: regex

I need to enforce a format for a field "2011-12 whatever else after"

The hyphen needs to be included between the digits, and no spaces until after the second digit in the year. I think the hyphen is throwing this off. I've played with Expresso but to no avail.

`\d{4}-0[1-9]|1[0-2].*` What's wrong with this?

Comment: Am I to understand you want four digits followed by a hyphen followed by two digits a space, and then anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Try `^\d{4}-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])\s`

If you don't need the trailing space remove `\s`.

This matches:

```
Sequence: match all of the following in order
  BeginOfLine
  Repeat
    Digit
    4 times
  -
  CapturingGroup
    GroupNumber:1
    OR: match either of the following
      Sequence: match all of the following in order
        1
        AnyCharIn[ 0 to 2]
      Sequence: match all of the following in order
        0
        AnyCharIn[ 1 to 9]
  WhiteSpaceCharacter
```

Comment: After looking over your original code, it may just be you forgot the capture group to provide appropriate context for the OR description.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding the requirements, this should work fine:

> `^2011-12.*`